# Removing elements from array Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

Let's say I am trying to remove elements from array `a = [1,1,1,2,2,3]`. If I perform the following:

```
b = a - [1,3]
```

Then I will get:

```
b = [2,2]
```

However, I want the result to be

```
b = [1,1,2,2]
```

i.e. I only remove one instance of each element in the subtracted vector not all cases. Is there a simple way in Ruby to do this?

Comment: if you subtract `[1,1,3]` do you want to end up with `b = [1,2,2]`? Or is that never going to happen?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You may do:

```
a= [1,1,1,2,2,3]
delete_list = [1,3]
delete_list.each do |del|
    a.delete_at(a.index(del))
end
```

result : [1, 1, 2, 2]

Comment: So array-subtraction is actually disjoint-Set?

Comment: Array Difference---Returns a new array that is a copy of the original array, removing any items that also appear in other_ary. (If you need set-like behavior, see the library class Set.) [link](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html)

Comment: If you wanted to remove all instances of items in `delete_list`, you could do this. `b = a.each.reject{|x| delete_list.each.include? x}`

Comment: I'm guessing I'm misreading it, but why wouldn't the result be [1,1,2,3] ? if you are removing indexes 1 and 3 from `a` ?

Comment: @moopasta, because he's deleting the first occurring 1 and 3, from beginning to end of array. He's actually calling a delete_at, which deleted the index of the a Array with the FIRST OCCURRENCE of the 1, and then the 3. So he's, in this case, issuing a a.delete_at(0) and then a a.delete_at(4)

Answer (score 8):

```
[1,3].inject([1,1,1,2,2,3]) do |memo,element|
  memo.tap do |memo|
    i = memo.find_index(e)
    memo.delete_at(i) if i
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Not very simple but:

```
a = [1,1,1,2,2,3]
b = a.group_by {|n| n}.each {|k,v| v.pop [1,3].count(k)}.values.flatten
=> [1, 1, 2, 2]
```

Also handles the case for multiples in the 'subtrahend':

```
a = [1,1,1,2,2,3]
b = a.group_by {|n| n}.each {|k,v| v.pop [1,1,3].count(k)}.values.flatten
=> [1, 2, 2]
```

EDIT: this is more an enhancement combining Norm212 and my answer to make a "functional" solution.

```
b = [1,1,3].each.with_object( a ) { |del| a.delete_at( a.index( del ) ) }
```

Put it in a lambda if needed:

```
subtract = lambda do |minuend, subtrahend|
  subtrahend.each.with_object( minuend ) { |del| minuend.delete_at( minuend.index( del ) ) }
end
```

then:

```
subtract.call a, [1,1,3]
```

Comment: No, order could be altered. Looks like Norm212 does preserve order.

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution I frequently use:

```
arr = ['remove me',3,4,2,45]

arr[1..-1]

=> [3,4,2,45]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [1,1,1,2,2,3]
a.slice!(0) # remove first index
a.slice!(-1) # remove last index
# a = [1,1,2,2] as desired
```

Answer (score 0):

For speed, I would do the following, which requires only one pass through each of the two arrays. This method preserves order. I will first present code that does not mutate the original array, then show how it can be easily modified to mutate.

```
arr = [1,1,1,2,2,3,1]
removals = [1,3,1]

h = removals.group_by(&:itself).transform_values(&:size)
  #=> {1=>2, 3=>1} 
arr.each_with_object([]) { |n,a|
  h.key?(n) && h[n] > 0 ? (h[n] -= 1) : a << n }
  #=> [1, 2, 2, 1]

arr
  #=> [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1]
```

To mutate `arr` write:

```
h = removals.group_by(&:itself).transform_values(&:count)
arr.replace(arr.each_with_object([]) { |n,a|
  h.key?(n) && h[n] > 0 ? (h[n] -= 1) : a << n })
  #=> [1, 2, 2, 1]

arr
  #=> [1, 2, 2, 1]
```

This uses the 21<sup>st</sup> century method [Hash#transform_values](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values) (new in MRI v2.4), but one could instead write:

```
h = Hash[removals.group_by(&:itself).map { |k,v| [k,v.size] }]
```

or

```
h = removals.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { | n,h| h[n] += 1 }
```