# How can I remove an item in a Ruby array based on its content?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm making a sort of variable system in Ruby where a user can create a variable. Provided they give a variable name and contents, it adds the name and string given to an array, adding two more items to the array. Here's the code:

```rb
$vars = []
  def create(name, value)
    $vars << name
    $vars << value
  end
```

I also want to add a "delete" option where the user types `delete("varName")` and behind the scenes, it searches for an item with the same value in the `$vars` array and deletes it. Is there any way to do this? Also, is there any way to get the number of the item (e.g. items in the array are `["a", "b", "c", "d"]` and the user wants to delete `"d"`,and then the program returns 3, since that's the location of `"d"`.

Comment: Since Ruby v1.8 it has not been possible to create local variables dynamically.

Comment: The items in your array will not be `["a", "b", "c", "d"]`. They will be `["a", "a's value", "b", "b's value", ...]`

Comment: Do try and steer *far, far away* from global variables in Ruby. These are prefixed with `$` and should only be used in exceptional circumstances. The Ruby way of doing this, presuming it's not some [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) that has a better solution, is to create a class with an `@vars` instance variable, then manipulate that using an object instance method like `create` or, even better, `[]=(name, value)`. How this is different from a Hash, I don't know.

Comment: It's worth noting that Ruby can already create actual variables with `instance_variable_set` and `local_variable_set`. You don't need to fake it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [Hash](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html) is used to store pairs of items. It is faster, and guarantees names will be unique.

```
$vars = {}
def create(name, value)
  $vars[name] = value
end
```

Then deleting is trivial.

```
$vars.delete(name)
```

As is finding the value.

```
value = $vars[name]
```

Hashes remember the order in which keys were added. [`$vars.keys`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-keys) will return an Array of the names in the order they were added. Then you can use [`find_index`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-find_index) to get where it appears in the list of keys.

```
index = $vars.keys.find_index(name)
```

Aside from letting the user know the order in which variables are declared, this isn't of much use. Variables don't have an order.

---

If you wanted to do this with arrays, first we'd fix `create`. It's storing both the key and the value in the same Array.

```
create(a, 23)
create(b, 42)

# $var = ['a', 23, 'b', 42]
```

Instead, store each pair in its own array.

```
def create(name, value)
  $vars << [name, value]
end

create(a, 23)
create(b, 42)

# $var = [['a', 23], ['b', 42]]
```

Then to delete, search just the first elements of each pair using [`index`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-index). Then delete that index.

```
def delete(name)
  idx = $vars.map(&:first).index(name)
  $vars.delete_at(idx) if idx

  return idx
end
```

Finding the value of a name would work similarly. Find the index of the matching name, look up that pair, return its second element (the value).

```
def find(name)
  idx = $vars.map(&:first).index(name)
  pair = $vars[idx]
  return pair[1]
end
```

But don't do this, use a Hash.

Answer (score 0):

```
$vars = ["name", "value", "item"]
index = $vars.index("name")
$vars.delete_at(index)
```

Sources:

1. [Duplicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8929053/removing-elements-from-array-ruby)
2. [Editor](https://repl.it/languages/ruby)
3. [Documentation](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/index)

Although if this is rails, is it really a good idea to use a GLOBAL variable?

Comment: I'd recommend reading these: See "[Don’t use “click here” and other common hyperlink mistakes](https://medium.com/@heyoka/dont-use-click-here-f32f445d1021)".
"[Don't use "click here" as link text](https://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/noClickHere)"
"[Links and Hypertext - Link Text and Appearance](https://webaim.org/techniques/hypertext/link_text)"

Comment: @theTinMan The links describe what I link...and editor...the documentation for index and a source that might be a duplicate..whats the issue?

Comment: The issue is, links rot then break. _When_ they break, what will this tell us? Instead, you're supposed to summarize the important point of the link that you're trying to make, appropriately attributed, so _when_ the link breaks, the answer continues to make sense. We answer questions, not as much for the person asking, but for those who are looking for a solution in the future. Imagine your answer with broken links. How useful would it be?

Comment: @theTinMan understood.